# Convert emty list `[]` to `[0]` pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Sample data

```
        A
0      []
1  [1, 3]
2  [5, 7]
3      []
```

Desired output:

```
        A
0     [0]
1  [1, 3]
2  [5, 7]
3     [0]
```

How can i replace null list to `[0]`?
I tried `df.A.replace([],[0])` and `df.apply(lambda x:x if x!=[] else [0])` but these gave me errors

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x:x if x!=[] else [0])` should work. what error message do you get?

Comment: @HaleemurAli this `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`

Comment: ah, i see, nvm, that is the expected error. the apply must be made on the series. see my answer for how to fix your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
df.loc[~df.A.astype(bool),'A']=[[0] for x in range(sum(df.A.astype(bool))) ]
```

Notice the reason why i use for loop, is try to avoid same object assign twice

Like

```
df.loc[~df.A.astype(bool),'A']=[[0]]
```

Detail

```
df1=df.copy()
df2=df.copy()
df1.loc[~df1.A.astype(bool),'A']=[[0] for x in range(sum(df1.A.astype(bool))) ]
df2.loc[~df2.A.astype(bool),'A']=[[0]]
df1.iloc[0,0]+=[1]
df1
Out[447]: 
        A
0  [0, 1]
1  [1, 3]
2  [5, 7]
3     [0]
df2.iloc[0,0]+=[1]
df2
Out[449]: 
        A
0  [0, 1]
1  [1, 3]
2  [5, 7]
3  [0, 1]#same object so change at the same time , even not adjust this row
```

Comment: isn't first one complex? I can have same advantage with second solution also, right?

Comment: @anonymous check the detail ~

Answer (score 2):

use an apply on the series and assign back to `df.A`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[], [1, 3], [5, 7], []]})
df.A = df.A.apply(lambda x: [0] if x == [] else x)
df
# outputs
        A
0     [0]
1  [1, 3]
2  [5, 7]
3     [0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way:

```
>>> df.A = df.A.apply(lambda x: x if x == [] else [0])
>>> df
        A
0     [0]
1  [1, 3]
2  [5, 7]
3     [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a DataFrame with those values you can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [[0],[1,3],[2,3],[0]]
```